is Possible to take screenshots / take pictures / record what i am seeing using aframe?
Hi guys i am doing a small exercise using aframe in a HTML file what i want to do now is be able to download the 3d image that im seeing, like "taking a picture or video"


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AR Photo Capture</title>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.3.2/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
        #takePhotoButton {
            position: fixed;
            top: 20px;
            right: 20px;
            padding: 12px 24px;
            color: white;
            background-color: #007bff;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            z-index: 999; /* Ensure it's on top of everything */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<a-scene embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam;' renderer="preserveDrawingBuffer: true">
        <a-marker preset="hiro">
            <a-box position="0 0.5 0" material="color: red;"></a-box>
        </a-marker>
        <a-entity camera></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
    <button id="takePhotoButton">Take Photo</button>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('takePhotoButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
            const sceneCanvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
            if (sceneCanvas) {
                html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
                    // Create a canvas to merge them
                    var finalCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    var ctx = finalCanvas.getContext('2d');

                    // Set dimensions
                    finalCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                    finalCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;

                    // Draw the AR content
                    ctx.drawImage(sceneCanvas, 0, 0);

                    // Draw the html2canvas result
                    ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);

                    // Convert to DataURL or Blob
                    var dataUrl = finalCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                    var link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.href = dataUrl;
                    link.download = 'combined-ar-photo.png';
                    link.click();
                });
            }
        });
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>



This is my current output
i was trying a solution using html2canvas but not sure if i am missing something because the image i am getting in my device is not saving the 3d content
in order the code to work you might need to scan the hiro bookmark that can be found here as well
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/data/images/hiro.png
